# Insert & Retrieve from a channel in same main function throws "goroutine 1 [chan receive]: main.main() /path exit status 2" error

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

An very new to GO & am trying to understand channels. I am trying to create a main function which will be inserting elements into a channel & printing it from the channel all in the same function.
But am not able to do so without making the inserting part a separate function which is then run as a go routine.
But am not able to understand why the same code wont work in a single main function in a single thread. I get the error "goroutine 1 [chan receive]: main.main() /path exit status 2".

Working Code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func inserChannel(c chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < cap(c); i++ {
        c <- i * i
    }
    defer close(c)
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 10)
    go inserChannel(c)
    for i := range c {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

What I am trying:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 10)
    for i := 0; i < cap(c); i++ {
        c <- i * i
    }
    defer close(c)
    for i := range c {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

I want to understand why the first will work & the second wont. It even works when I run it as a normal function i.e., not a go routine but wont if all code are in a single main function.

Comment: Hint: ask yourself under what conditions the `for i := range c` terminates, and at what time your deferred function call executes.

Answer (score 0):

Second code: 
It doesn't work because it attempts to send and receive on the channel within the same main function, without goroutines. 
Reason: The `for i := 0; i < cap(c); i++` loop starts sending values to the channel. When it sends the first value, it blocks, waiting for a receiver. The subsequent `for i := range c` loop is supposed to receive those values, but it never gets a chance to start because the first loop is already blocked. This creates a circular dependency where each operation blocks the other, leading to the deadlock and the "goroutine 1 [chan receive]: main.main() /path exit status 2" error.

The first code works because it leverages goroutines to run the sending and receiving operations concurrently. The `go inserChannel(c)` line launches a new goroutine that executes the inserChannel function independently. This goroutine starts sending values to the channel, allowing the main function to proceed to the `for i := range c` loop to receive them.

Comment: But it also works by directly calling the function without go routine so how does it work?

Comment: "When it sends the first value, it blocks, waiting for a receiver." This is incorrect. The channel is buffered and therefore sending does not block.